# Interfaces on ServiceModel request objects in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'd like to define an interface on some of my servicestack service model request dto objects. I've defined the interface in my service model project and added it to the dto objects.

But in the client application when I use the "Update Service Stack Reference" function with the Visual Studio plugin, my interface definitions are not being added to my DTOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously the only interfaces included in the [Add ServiceStack Reference](http://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference) feature are existing interfaces defined in the dep-free **ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll** to reduce coupling with external libraries but support for exporting (non-generic) implemented interfaces were just added from **v4.5.13** which is now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

An alternative to having interfaces generated is including them in partial class that sits alongside the generated DTOs which define the interfaces you want each DTO to share, e.g:

```
public partial class MyDto : IMyInterface {}
```

The previous behavior of not exporting implemented interfaces can be reverted with:

```
var nativeTypes = this.GetPlugin<NativeTypesFeature>();
nativeTypes.MetadataTypesConfig.ExcludeImplementedInterfaces = true;
```